# Could not infer type of parameter

Tags: list, scala, generics

I have created `MyList` abstract class to implement the list, the reason for not using already present list implementation is I am learning Scala and this was exercise for the same course. I am writing a `zipWith` function to create a new list with concatenation of individual items for example:

list 1: list = `[1,2,3]`
list 2: listOfStrings = `["Hello", "This is", "Scala"]`

and I am expecting output like: `[1-Hello, 2-This is, 3-Scala]`

I wrote `zipWith` function as mentioned below:

```
  override def zipWith[B, C](list: MyList[B], zip: (A, B) => C): MyList[C] = {
    if(list.isEmpty) throw  new RuntimeException("Lists do not have the same length")
    else new Cons(zip(h, list.head), t.zipWith(list.tail, zip))
  }
```

And I am trying to call this function using this statement:

```
println(list.zipWith[String, String](listOfStrings, (Int,String)=>_+"-"+_))
```

But I am getting an error:

> I could not infer the type of the parameter *$3 of expanded function:
> (*$3, _$4) => _$3 + "-" + _$4.

Type for this variable is clearly mentioned as `Int` still I am getting this error. This could be solved using:

```
println(list.zipWith[String, String](listOfStrings, _+"-"+_))
```

I am not able to understand why earlier statement fails, even after giving the type for the required variable

Comment: As an advice, stay away from the `_` syntax for creating lambdas, it doesn't always behave as expected and IMHO is confusing to newcomers. - BTW, also prefer string interpolation over raw concatenation.

Comment: Indeed, I find  _  syntax confusing. I agree string interpolation is more cleaner than raw concatenation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax `(Int,String)=>_+"-"+_` doesn't mean what you think.

It represents a function taking two parameters with some name but unknown type: `(Int: ???, String: ???) => _+"-"+_`.

Thus the compiler is raising an error because it indeed have no clue about the types.

You should either:

- write it with explicit variable names: `(i: Int, s: String) => s"$i-$s"`. (Notice the usage of interpolation which is recommended over adding int and string),
- or declare the function separately like this: `val f: (Int, String) => String = _+"-"+_`.

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful. I need to get my syntax in order.

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is confused on which variable to match each underscore. This explicit expression works for me:

```
println(list.zipWith[String, String](listOfStrings, (a:Int, b:String) => a+"-"+b))
```